# Element disappearing under layers despite z-index: 4 (highest layer)

Tags: html, css

Despite having used z-index: 4 (highest layer) and it being correctly applied as I can see through the browser console, an element keeps disappearing from the screen. Any pointers welcome.

Please see links to images below (can't embed image in question yet, because of my Stackoverflow karma, so please bear with me). Relevant code below:

- [Element disapearing under the yellowish overlay to the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBsSZ.png)
- [Element gone from the view, hidden (I guess) under the yellowish
  overlay to the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rvdty.png)
- [No issues with the mobile view, z:index 4 showing up correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQkDI.png)

```css
    html {
 height: 100%
}


h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
 font-family: Merriweather;
 font-weight: 700
}



body {
 height: 100%;
 min-height: 35rem;
 position: relative;
 font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
 font-weight: 300;
}

html, body {
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

video {
 position: fixed;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 min-width: 100%;
 min-height: 100%;
 width: auto;
 height: auto;
 transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
 z-index: 0
}



@media (pointer:coarse) and (hover:none) {
 body {
  background: url(../img/bg-mobile-fallback.jpg) #002e66 no-repeat center center scroll;
  background-position: cover
 }

 body video {
  display: none
 }

}

.overlay {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #cd9557;
 opacity: .7;
 z-index: 1
}

.masthead {
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
 padding-bottom: 3rem;
 height: 80%;
 z-index: 3
}

.masthead .masthead-bg {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 min-height: 35rem;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: rgba(0, 46, 102, .8);
 transform: skewY(4deg);
 transform-origin: bottom right
}

.masthead .masthead-content h1 {
 font-size: 2.5rem
}

.masthead .masthead-content p {
 font-size: 1.2rem
}

.masthead .masthead-content p strong {
 font-weight: 700
}

.masthead .masthead-content .input-group-newsletter input {
 font-size: 1rem;
 padding: 1rem
}

.masthead .masthead-content .input-group-newsletter button {
 font-size: .8rem;
 font-weight: 700;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 padding: 1rem
}

@media (min-width:768px) {
 .masthead {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 0;
  width: 40.5rem;
  padding-bottom: 0
 }

 .masthead .masthead-bg {
  min-height: 0;
  transform: skewX(-8deg);
  transform-origin: top right
 }

 .masthead .masthead-content {
  padding-left: 3rem;
  padding-right: 10rem
 }

 .masthead .masthead-content h1 {
  font-size: 3.5rem
 }

 .masthead .masthead-content p {
  font-size: 1.3rem
 }

}

.social-icons {
 position: absolute;
 margin-bottom: 2rem;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 2
}

.social-icons ul {
 margin-top: 2rem;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center
}

.social-icons ul>li {
 margin-left: .75rem;
 margin-right: .75rem;
 display: inline-block
}

.social-icons ul>li>a {
 display: block;
 color: #fff;
 background-color: rgba(0, 46, 102, .8);
 border-radius: 100%;
 font-size: 1rem;
 line-height: 2rem;
 height: 2rem;
 width: 2rem
}

@media (min-width:768px) {
 .social-icons {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 2.5rem;
  bottom: 2rem;
  width: auto
 }

 .social-icons ul {
  margin-top: 0;
  width: auto
 }

 .social-icons ul>li {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-bottom: 2rem
 }

 .social-icons ul>li:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0
 }

 .social-icons ul>li>a {
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  width: 2rem
 }

 .social-icons ul>li>a:hover {
  background-color: #002e66
 }

}

@media (min-width:768px) {
 .mastfoot {
  color: #999 !important;
   color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5) !important;
  position: absolute !important;
  bottom: 10px !important;
  margin-left: 4rem !important;
  margin-right: 10rem !important;
  z-index: 3
 }

 .inner-mastfoot {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  text-align: left !important
 }

}

.btn-secondary {
 background-color: #cd9557;
 border-color: #cd9557;
 border-top-right-radius: 6px !important;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 6px !important;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
 border-top-left-radius: 0
}

.btn-secondary:active,
.btn-secondary:focus,
.btn-secondary:hover {
 background-color: #ba7c37!important;
 border-color: #ba7c37!important
}

.input {
 font-weight: 300!important
}

.mastfoot {
 color: #262626;
 color: rgba(26, 26, 26, .5);
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 10px;
 width: 100%;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 z-index: 3
}

.inner-mastfoot {
 font-size: 0.8rem;
 text-align: center
}

.inner-mastfoot a {
 color: inherit;
 border-bottom-width: 1px;
 border-bottom-style: dotted;
 border-bottom-color: initial;
 text-decoration: none;
 -moz-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out, border-bottom-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
 -webkit-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out, border-bottom-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out, border-bottom-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
 transition: color 0.2s ease-out, border-bottom-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

 .inner-mastfoot a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: bolder;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
}

@media (min-width:768px) {

 .nav-masthead .nav-link {
    color: #262626 !important;
     color: rgba(26, 26, 26, .5) !important;
 }

 .nav-masthead .nav-link:hover,
 .nav-masthead .nav-link:focus {
   border-bottom-color: rgba(26, 26, 26, .5) !important;
 }

 .nav-masthead .active {
     color: #000 !important;
     border-bottom-color: #000 !important;
 }
}

.masthead__navigation {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  padding-bottom: 0 !important;
  width: 100vw !important;
}

.inner-masthead {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  z-index: 4 !important
}

.nav-masthead .nav-link {
    padding: .25rem 0;
    font-weight: 700;
   color: #999;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
    background-color: transparent;
    border-bottom: .25rem solid transparent;
   z-index: 4 !important
}

.nav-masthead .nav-link:hover,
.nav-masthead .nav-link:focus {
    border-bottom-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}

.nav-masthead .nav-link + .nav-link {
    margin-left: 1rem;
}

.nav-masthead .active {
    color: #fff;
    border-bottom-color: #fff;
}

@media (min-width: 48em) {
 .inner-masthead {
     float: left;
 }
 .nav-masthead {
     float: right;
 }
}
```

```html
   

 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>X</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom fonts for this template -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather:300,300i,400,400i,700,700i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="css/coming-soon.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/codechair.github.io-integrante/assets/images/favicon/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/codechair.github.io-integrante/assets/images/favicon/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/codechair.github.io-integrante/assets/images/favicon/favicon-16x16.png">
    <link rel="manifest" href="/codechair.github.io-integrante/assets/images/favicon/site.webmanifest">
    <link rel="mask-icon" href="/codechair.github.io-integrante/assets/images/favicon/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/codechair.github.io-integrante/assets/images/favicon/favicon.ico">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
    <meta name="msapplication-config" content="/codechair.github.io-integrante/assets/images/favicon/browserconfig.xml">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <video playsinline="playsinline" autoplay="autoplay" muted="muted" loop="loop">
      <source src="mp4/bg.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>

  <div class="masthead">
    <header class="masthead__navigation mb-auto d-flex w-100 p-3 mx-auto flex-column">
      <div class="inner">
        <a class="inner-masthead" href="{{ '/' | absolute_url }}"><img src="/assets/images/logo.jpg" style="max-height:40px; width:auto;"></a>
        <nav class="nav nav-masthead justify-content-center">
          <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Home</a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Blog</a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Join Newsletter</a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
      <div class="masthead-bg"></div>
      <div class="container h-100">
        <div class="row h-100">
          <div class="col-12 my-auto">
            <div class="masthead-content text-white py-5 py-md-0">
              <h1 class="mb-3">Register</h1>
              <p class="mb-5">Building a X.
              We're building X for you. <strong>Request an invitation for early access using the form below!</strong></p>
              <form action="https://hen.us18.list-manage.com/subscribe/post" method="POST" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" target="_blank">
                <input type="hidden" name="u" value="377b993ba697354f6584371c9">
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="e1c7ba1f4b">
                <div class="input-group input-group-newsletter">
                  <input type="email" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" name="MERGE0" id="MERGE0" size="25" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your email..." aria-label="Enter email..." aria-describedby="basic-addon">
                  <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit">Notify Me!</button>
                  </div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="ht" value="f5b0455009025ab4743b2ecc932316028905c673:MTUzMTgyNjMzMC43NDM3">
                    <input type="hidden" name="mc_signupsource" value="hosted">
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  <div class="mastfoot">
      <div class="inner-mastfoot">
        &copy; 2018 X Ltd. All Rights Reserved. &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; • &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="/legal">Legal</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; • &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="/contact">Contact</a>
      </div>
  </div>

    <div class="social-icons">
      <ul class="list-unstyled text-center mb-0">
        <li class="list-unstyled-item">
          <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="list-unstyled-item">
          <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="list-unstyled-item">
          <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-medium"></i>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="list-unstyled-item">
          <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="list-unstyled-item">
          <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="list-unstyled-item">
          <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>




    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom scripts for this template -->
    <script src="js/coming-soon.min.js"></script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You combined everything here :p opacity, transform, etc a lot of stacking context

Comment: @TemaniAfif that could be the reason I can't find what is going wrong... :p

Comment: and at the end it's a simple overflow issue :p ... you define an inner element to be 100vw and it's overflowing the container where you defined overflow:hidden

Comment: without that 100vw, the navigation links were going only to the middle of the page (where the blue background ends i.e. a very broken design). So, I've forced the navigation bar to go to the end of the screen. So, what do you suggest I do?

Comment: you should make the navigation outside, this is not a good way to do .. you are forcing an element to be bigger than it's container and you are applying overflow:hidden so there is no way to see it

Comment: you mean making the navigation outside 'masthead'? Tried that before and was getting a longer screen than a simple masthead-type design (things became scroll-able, too many spaces, etc...) I blame my incompetence. Any way of fixing by removing the 'overflow:hidden'? Would that be a possible fix?

Comment: well, I would avoid fixing this as you will simply end up with a lot of hacks ... better re-think and adjust the layout as IMHO you are using a lot of code to create a simple layout

Comment: Thx, have applied the hack this time (aware not optimal). Should you want to get an answer together, I’ll be happy to approve

Comment: you can answer your own question describing what you have done to fix the issue ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Masthead`, the container to `masthead__navigation`, had been set `overflow: hidden`, while `masthead__navigation`had been set to overflow with a forced `width: 100vw`.

The fix was to set `overflow: visible` for the cases in which the CSS wasn't working

> i.e. for Desktop

```
@media (min-width:768px) {
    .masthead {
        height: 100%;
        min-height: 0;
        width: 40.5rem;
        padding-bottom: 0;
        overflow: visible
    }
```

This made the screen scroll horizontally, so `overflow: hidden` applied to `body` stopped the scrolling:

```
html, body {
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```